# Weird behavior of css class in td with rowspan (Angular)

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm using a custom css class called 'td-group' to customize td with a rowspan, to be more specific [attr.rowspan] since i'm using angular. In short words, the css style doesn't always get applied correctly, i've looked everywhere and tried everything and still didn't figure it out
The bug only occurs on chrome and never in edge
[Here the image of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmF5j.png)

```
<tr *ngFor="let r of list; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="group && r.representative.show">
    <td class="td-group" [attr.rowspan]="r.representative.height">
      {{r.representative.name}}          
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <td *ngFor="let c of cols">
    {{r[c.name]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yr3pxq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Hello, and welcome! Can you create a stackblitz with the code?

Comment: @Hoch here is the stackblitz, change  rapidly from a botton to another ant the bug will happen. I forfot to mention that this bug only happens in chrome e not in edge.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yr3pxq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Can't reproduce here, maybe other style from page will influence your table? Print using chrome: https://prnt.sc/15pf2uz

Comment: @Hoch have you tried clicking buttons multiples times ?

Comment: Yes, just clicked a lot of times and  rapidly, i don't know how to record a gif to share..